# Swing going from menu to actual gameplay

Tags: java, swing

So I am making a space invaders clone. Originally I had no problem getting my game to work with a simple main class that created the frame, created the gameplay and started the thread.

But then I tried to implement a start menu and it all went to crap. The menu appears with success but the gameplay does not appear when I press start.

I am running out of ideas and I am completely stumped. I am somewhat new as well to SO, so if there is anything I left out, I appreciate any help.

**Here is the original with no menu that worked fine:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpaceRaiders");

    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Gameplay gameplay = new Gameplay();
    frame.add(gameplay);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(gameplay);
    t1.start();


}
```

**However, the moment I tried to implement a menu to then play the game, I am running into all sorts of trouble. I created a UI class as well as an actual "game" class like so:**

```
public class UI {

JFrame frame, f2;
JPanel titrePanel, startButtonPanel, loadButtonPanel, p2;
JLabel nomJeu;
JButton startButton, loadButton;
Font fontTitre, fontStart;
Gameplay gameplay;

public void createUI(ChoixJeu cj) {
    frame = new JFrame("SpaceRaiders");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.setLayout(null);

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //------------------ECRAN MENU---------------------
    //Titre
    titrePanel = new JPanel();
    titrePanel.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 100);
    titrePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    Font fontTitre = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 50);
    Font fontStart = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    nomJeu = new JLabel("SpaceRaiders");
    nomJeu.setForeground(Color.white);
    nomJeu.setFont(fontTitre);
    titrePanel.add(nomJeu);

    //Start button
    startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    startButtonPanel.setBounds(200, 400, 200, 40);
    startButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    startButton = new JButton("START");
    startButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    startButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    startButton.setFont(fontStart);
    startButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    startButton.addActionListener(cj);
    startButton.setActionCommand("start");
    startButtonPanel.add(startButton);

    //Load Button
    loadButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    loadButtonPanel.setBounds(200, 440, 200, 100);
    loadButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    loadButton = new JButton("LOAD");
    loadButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    loadButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    loadButton.setFont(fontStart);
    loadButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    titrePanel.add(nomJeu);
    loadButtonPanel.add(loadButton);

    frame.add(startButtonPanel);
    frame.add(titrePanel);

    //------------------ECRAN MENU FIN---------------------   
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

**And the game class...**

```
public class Jeu {

ChoixJeu cj = new ChoixJeu();
UI ui = new UI();
Ecrans e = new Ecrans(ui);
Gameplay gp;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Jeu();


}

public Jeu() {

    ui.createUI(cj);
    Gameplay gameplay = new Gameplay();
    this.gp = gameplay;

}

public class ChoixJeu implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        String yourChoice = ae.getActionCommand();

        switch (yourChoice) {
            case "start":
                e.montrerEcranJeu();
                new Thread(gp).start();
                ui.frame.add(gp);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

}

**I also tried to make a class/method that hides the menu panels**

```
    public void montrerEcranJeu() {
    //Cache Menu
    ui.titrePanel.setVisible(false);
    ui.startButtonPanel.setVisible(false);


    //Montre Jeu
    // ui.frame.add(gameplay);
}
```

**And just in case the Gameplay class. The run() method is at the bottom**

```
public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener, Runnable {

private Ship player = new Ship(new Point(200, 555));
Timer t = new Timer(5, this);


private ArrayList<Laser> lasers = new ArrayList<Laser>();
private int laserNb;
private boolean readytofire;
private boolean shot = false;


private ArrayList<Invader> invaders = new ArrayList<Invader>();

private boolean pause;

public Gameplay() {
    super();
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    for (int j = 0; j < 80; j += 20) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            invaders.add(new Invader(5 + i * 30, j));
        }
    }
}

public boolean addLaser(Laser a) {
    lasers.add(a);
    return true;
}

public boolean addPlayer(Ship p) {

    this.player = p;

    return true;
}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT == e.getKeyCode()) {
        moveRight();
    }
    if (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT == e.getKeyCode()) {
        moveLeft();
    }
    if (KeyEvent.VK_SPACE == e.getKeyCode()) {
        shoot();
        System.out.println("Space Action from Gameplay is working");
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    repaint();
}


public void moveRight() {
    if (player.getCentre().getX() >= 580) {
        player.setX(580);
    } else {
        double movement = player.getCentre().getX();
        movement += 10;
        player.setX(movement);
    }
    this.repaint();
}

public void moveLeft() {
    if (player.getCentre().getX() <= 20) {
        player.setX(20);
    } else {
        double movement = player.getCentre().getX();
        movement -= 10;
        player.setX(movement);
    }
    this.repaint();
}


public void shoot() {

    shot = true;
    if (readytofire) {
        Point top = new Point(player.getTopX(), player.getTopY());
        Laser laser = new Laser(top);
        addLaser(laser);

    }
}


public void moveShot() {
    if (shot) {
        for (Laser l : lasers) {
            l.setY(l.getTopLeft().getY() - 1);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setBackground(Color.black);
    super.paint(g);
    player.draw(g);
    for (Laser l : lasers) {
        l.draw(g);
    }
    for (Invader i : invaders) {
        i.draw(g);
    }

}

// public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
// Controle Thread
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        moveShot();

        for (Invader i : invaders) {
            i.moveAndUpdate();

        }
        //  for (Invader i : invaders) {
        //         if (){
        //            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD!");
        //        } 

        //  }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            readytofire = true;

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gameplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Too much code; I doubt anyone will read all of that.  Please create a [mcve] for us.  Also please be *specific and detailed* in your question.  What does "all goes to crap" actually mean?  What do you see happen, and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

So, using `null` layouts is the beginning of your problems.  I might recommend using `CardLayout` which is designed to help you dynamically switch between views. See [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details.  I'd also suggest taking the time to read through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and finding one or more appropriate layouts to support your menu.

You're also making a lot of fundamental mistakes.  Swing is not thread safe, so you should avoid updating the UI (or something the UI depends on) from outside the context of the EDT - see [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution.

As a general recommendation, you should avoid overriding `paint` and, in the case of classes which extend from `JComponent`, prefer `paintComponent` instead.  You should also avoid call methods which might change the state of the component during a paint cycle, this can increase the number of repaint requests and degrade the performance of your program (ie, don't call `setBackground` inside paint).

Have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how the paint system works and how best you can work with it.

You should also avoid `KeyListener`, this is likely to cause you issues when you introduce other, focusable, components into the picture.  Instead, you should favour the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

> I've read through [insert link or tutorial], but it still doesn't help...

And forgive me if this doesn't happen all the time.

The point of providing you the tutorial links is to encourage you to learn something;

- Learn where to find answers to your questions
- Learn how the APIs work
- Expand your knowledge and understanding of how the APIs work

Having said that, they're not always "obvious" as to the solution.  What I do when I'm in this situation is start with one or more new projects, dedicated to just working on that aspect of the API I'm trying to understand.  For here I can explore the concepts in isolation and when I "think" I understand them, try and implement them into the project I'm working on.  This might take a number of iterations, but once it works, I have gained a much deeper understanding and appreciation of the API then I would have gained from a simple "copy-n-paste" solution

Comment: Your response is fantastic and it sent me down quite the rabbit hole. I have no found the solution yet, but I did apply a card layout and already I am seeing great progress. I have successfully swapped from the first panel by pressing a button to a second that plays the game. Currently I am unable to resize the gameplay and it only appears partly in a tiny part of the frame... But at least I know it runs.

I really appreciate it and I will keep reading and applying what you have posted.